# Ruby exucution stuck at system() line

Tags: ruby, sh

This is my code snippet

```
def execution_start
  puts "About to start"
  system("appium")
  puts "Done!!"
end
```

When executing this I see the output `About to start`, and appium server is launched. But after that, I do not see anything happening. It's stuck forever. Any idea?

Comment: (it's not stuck forever, if you exit the "appium" app, your script will continue)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know kimmo lehto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`system` blocks until the command it runs has completed. To run a command and return immediately, use [`Process#spawn`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Process.html#method-c-spawn):

```
def execution_start
  puts "About to start"
  pid = Process.spawn("appium")
  puts "Done!!"
end
```

You can then use the returned PID to monitor whether the process has finished executing, and with what exit code, later in your program.

(Note that, per the documentation, you need to `Process#wait` the PID eventually, or at least register disinterest using `Process#detach` to prevent the subprocess from becoming a zombie.)

Comment: @VighneshPai: Glad I could help!